# Transfer openAM 9 configuration between environments

Tags: openam

I’m trying to find the least painful way of transporting config files between different environments and I have found many things that can break the system after the transport. I got a script that will keep the values for attributes correct for the ones that are depended on the environment but here is the list of couple of things that I’m not sure about. Maybe someone can shed some light on them.

What I want to do is to simply transport xml file based on the steps from the book for openAM 9 (simply export/import using ssoadm to xml file) but by analyzing the file in depth I find many differences that might break the system, so any help is appreciated.

1. In every xml file we have sections for ‘iplanet-am-auth-ldap-bind-passwd’ with hash value under it but in one xml file we’re missing one line with hash. I was wondering if we add that line with the correct hash value will it break the system or it won’t matter as long as the hash matches target environment?
2. Does the size of the ‘iplanet-am-logging-buffer-size’ has to match what was originally setup in the target environment or it will be ok if we overwrite the value from the source xml file?
3. For some reason we have different links in delegation-rules with the same name, for example:

   ```
   # environment1 - sms://dc=test-domain,dc=net/sunEntitlementService/1.0/application/ws/1/entitlement/entitlements

   # environment2 - sms://dc=test-domain,dc=net/sunEntitlementService/1.0/application/ws/1/entitlement/decision

   # environment3  - sms://*dc=test-domain,dc=net/sunIdentityRepositoryService/1.0/application/agent
   ```

It could be due the way the server was setup long time ago or due to development processes over time ( I don’t know) but my question is:

If the rule names are the same but some(or all) options/values are different between environments and we overwrite them with the source file from different environment, will this break things or it won’t matter ?